# Can I receive Bitcoin on any of my wallet addresses?

Tags: coinbase.com, address-reuse

Can I receive Bitcoin to any addresses from my wallet?

I have more than one address on Coinbase, and it seems to change every day. Can I turn off the changing of addresses?

Answer (score 6):

Yes! With an HD (Hierarchical Deterministic) wallet you control all the addresses inside of it. Using a new address for each transaction is actually a good thing for privacy.

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Deterministic_wallet

https://community.coinbase.com/t/why-did-my-address-change-did-i-lose-some-payments/1589/2

To answer your last question you don't need to stop your address from changing because payments send to your old HD addresses will remain under your control.

If you want more control I suggest you run your own full node and do not give any control to a 3rd party:
https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Coinbase offers convenience and other advantages but this post from CEO Brian Armstrong makes it clear what their priorities are:
https://medium.com/the-coinbase-blog/coinbase-is-not-a-wallet-b5b9293ca0e7

Comment: My friend sent to me 2.5 bitcoin a single address, but I have not got, and he told me he had contacted the company they told him he had sent to an old My addresses will not do returns Alpetkoan law does not protect dupes
I am very happy to help me

Comment: I want to help you but I need more information.  What "company" did your friend contact? If the "company" (I am assuming it was an online exchange or wallet) sent it to an old Coinbase address of yours you still should be able to access it. Every bitcoin transaction has a transaction ID. Ask your friend to request the transaction ID for the 2.5 bitcoins that were sent. You keep referring to an old address. Can you tell us what this address was? What address did your friend or the "company" he used send the bitcoins to? Please provide the address and transaction ID.

Comment: My wallet addresses on coinbase company also my friend same company .. If you know privacy for this company and if we can return we BTC or not ?
My friend tell me send to them about this problem but they are said no return money ..
i don’t think so

Answer (score 1):

As previously stated, please use a new address for each transaction to ensure the entire network is not run by people using 1 address for everything, we still need fungibility!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to buy new bitcoins and add them to my wallet but sent them to the receive address and not my personal wallet address. I have looked in the options at other addresses and the one I have sent the coins is in that list but I can't seem to find the funds anywhere ? Can anyone help ? Thanks

Comment: Your reply in this answer section is like a "me too" comment, which is generally not well appreciated.This section should contain an answer, which helps the original post. You may want to put it as a comment. If you want to raise (as) a different question, you may ask it by clicking "Ask Question".